# How to correct the scaling problem of the texture using UV wrap

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor

I applied a texture on a box using the UV smart. I remark that the texture is scaled. How to correct this problem?

[image: Texture image]
[image: Node]

[image: UV wrap result]

Comment: Did you apply the scale before unwrapping?

Comment: @Denis, What 's scale. I think, I did not do it?

Comment: @Denis, sorry, I did not understand what do you mean? How can i do it?

Comment: In object mode hit CTRL+A and select scale, then unwrap the object

Comment: @Denis, So I have to cancel What I have done and repeat?

Comment: @startingBlender read:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation

Comment: @Denis Add that as an answer please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid texture scaling on the mesh it is necessary to apply object scale before unwrapping. To apply the scale you need to be in object mode, then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select scale from the menu. Once scale is applied it is safe to unwrap the mesh without having scale distortion.

Comment: Even with CTRL+A in obj mode my model gets different texture scales and deformations...what's wrong according to you?